# store all possibles of a checkbox in mysql database using php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

![holidays][1]
![1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdRnV.png
my form is like this it is developed by using php and pdo mysql.
if i selected three checkboxes those names(independance, labor,...), start date those values should store in database 
I have tried with following code to insert data into database.

```
    $holidays = array(

            "Independence Day" => observed_day($_GET['y'],4,7),
            "Labor Day " => get_holiday($_GET['y'], 9,1, 1),
            "Columbus Day " => get_holiday($_GET['y'],10, 1, 2),
            "Halloween " => format_date($_GET["y"],10,31),
            "DST Ends " => date('I'),
            "Veteran's Day " => format_date($_GET["y"],11,11),
            "Thanksgiving " => get_holiday($_GET['y'],11, 4, 4),
            "Christmas Event " => format_date($_GET['y'],12,24),
            "Christmas Day " => format_date($_GET['y'],12,25),
            "New Year Event " => format_date($_GET['y'],12,31),
            "New Year's Day " => format_date($_GET['n'],1, 1),
            "Martin Luther King Day " => get_holiday($_GET['n'],1,1,3),
            "Valentine's Day " => format_date( $_GET['n'],2,14),
            "President's Day " => get_holiday($_GET['n'],2,1,3),
            "DST Begins " => date('I'),
            "St. Patrick's Day " => format_date($_GET['n'],3, 17),
            "Easter " => calculate_easter($_GET['n']),
            "Mother's Day " => get_holiday($_GET['n'],5, 0, 2),
            "Memorial Day " => get_holiday($_GET['n'],5, 1, '' ),
            "Father's Day " => get_holiday($_GET['n'],6, 0, 3)

            );

 //loop for holidays list
 foreach($holidays as $name => $dates)
 {
 echo "<tr>";
echo "<td width='30%'><input type='checkbox' name='holiday[]' id='".$name."'  value='".$dates."'></td>";
echo "<td width='75%'>".$name."</td>";
  echo "<td>" .$dates."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
 }
```

for retrieving i have used the following code

```
 $schoolyear = $_REQUEST['schoolyear'];
 $holiday = $_REQUEST['holiday'];
 $var = nl2br(implode(', ', $holiday));
 $periods = $_REQUEST['periods'];
 $start = $_REQUEST['start'];
 $end = $_REQUEST['end'];

 $start = date2mysql($start);
 $end = date2mysql($end);

$status = 1;
$visible = 1;

$test = 0;
if ($test == 1)
{
echo $schoolyear;
echo '<br />';
echo $start;
echo '<br />';
echo $end;
echo '<br />';
echo $status;
echo '<br />';
echo $_SESSION['user_account'];
  } 

 try {


  $sqladdyr = "INSERT INTO school_years (account_id,year_name,start,end,status,added,updated) VALUES (:a_id,:name,:start,:end,:status,NOW(),NOW())";

  $q = $conn->prepare($sqladdyr);

 $q->bindParam(":start", $start, PDO::PARAM_STR);
 $q->bindParam(":end", $end, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $q->bindParam(":a_id", $_SESSION['user_account'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $q->bindParam(":name", $schoolyear, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $q->bindParam(":status", $status, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $q->execute();

  $id = $conn->prepare("SELECT MAX(year_id) FROM school_years");  
                  //Set needed id.
  $id->execute();

   $id->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

   $id_val = $id->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

  echo $idval = $id_val[0];


  foreach($holiday as $key => $value){ 
echo $holiday[$key].'<br>';
echo $value.'<br>';
   $sql="INSERT INTO holidays (holiday_id,year_id,account_id,start,end,status,visible,added,updated) VALUES ('',:year_id,:aid,:date,:date,:status,:visible,NOW(),NOW())";
$sql = $conn->prepare($sql);
$sql->execute(array(
     ':year_id'=>$idval,
     ':aid'=>$_SESSION['user_account'],
    ':date'=>$holiday[$key],
     ':status'=>$status,
     ':visible'=>$visible,

   ));
  }

 } 
 catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();

  }
```

here, i am strucked. i dont know how to store holiday name and date at a time into the database for the selected multiple check boxes please any one help me.
      advance thanks

Comment: You are trying to save multiple holidays in a table right?
if it so you need to make it as a string separated by an comma or anything else.

Comment: Or else you can use many to many relationship in mySQL for storing multiple data related to one or many.
  Take look on it http://www.joinfu.com/2005/12/managing-many-to-many-relationships-in-mysql-part-1/

Answer (score 0):

I think PHP [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) work fine for you.

```
$holiday = serialize($_REQUEST['holiday']);
```

Then fetching the content from DB then use [unserialize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php)